# SQL Azure KeepAlive issues

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a VM hosted on Azure that connects to a SQL Azure DB. I run a third party application that crashes when the connection to Azure is closed after 30 minutes of being idle because it tries to update the DB  and the connection is closed.

I understand that the right thing to do would be have a try/catch routine to reconnect but it's a third party application and it would be hard for me to try that. Hence, I am trying to increase the keepalive time but with no sucess. I have followed the suggestions mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh290696(v=sql.110).aspx) but no luck. I have checked the registry on the VM and the keys were changed but the connection still closes after 30 minutes. I think it may be because the article is for cloud projects and requires a change in the services definition file, which I can't perform since I have only a VM and not cloud project. Also , I'm very new to Azure so I may be saying/doing something really stupid!

Thanks in advance.

The code I use for the .cmd file follows below :

```
if exist keepalive.txt goto done
time /t > keepalive.txt
REM Workaround for JDBC keep alive on SQL Azure
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters /v KeepAliveTime /t REG_DWORD /d 300000000 >> keepalive.txt
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters /v KeepAliveInterval /t REG_DWORD /d 100000 >> keepalive.txt
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters /v TcpMaxDataRetransmission /t REG_DWORD /d 10 >> keepalive.txt
shutdown /r /t 1
:done
```

### --------------------------------------------------------

**EDIT** :
Third party app was installed on the VM and it connects to SQL Azure through a JDBC driver.

Comment: how is your third party application connected with vm and sql azure

Comment: @TheGameiswar Sorry, forgot to mention. It was installed on the VM so runs directly there and connects to SQL Azure by jdbc.

Comment: also can you post some error messages ,application should connect to database when needed,i am not sure how your app is designed to crash when connection is killed after idle time

Comment: It crashes because it tries to update the DB but the connection was closed.

Comment: The MSDN documentation mentions that the registry settings are for the client side timeout, the Azure SQL gateway isn't influenced by these settings.

Comment: @Erik Oppedij thanks but I don't understand the implications of that. Does it mean that by changing the reigstry I'm not changing Azure's timeout?

Comment: Yes, the registry setting is for the local TCP stack, it has no effect on the Azure side

Comment: @Erik Oppedij okay I understand , what do you suggest I should do then?

Comment: The application should issue at least 1 query per 30 minutes, there is no other way I guess

Answer (score 1):

I think you are solving wrong problem here.

SQL Azure is cloud service, and you will face several different types of connection issues here, for example:

- **Connection Closed**, which you've faced with
- **Transient Failure** - service might just not be working right in this moment (but will work second later), just because it's Cloud
- **Throttling** - your service tier might not receive enough resources, or you just consumed all the resources you could in this time slot

Connection Close after 30 mins is just most obvious one, but you will for sure face the others too.

When dealing with cloud services you should think in "retry" mindset, and try to understand how to "retry" in case of error. Maybe most obvious solution will be to just restart your third party app in a loop, or write script to kill & restart it every 10 minutes etc.